# Getting rid of empty strings in a tuple

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

```
path = "C:/Users/bg/Documents/Brad/Code/Visual Studio/"

def getUnitTest(path):
    foundFiles = []

    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj'):
                path2 = os.path.split(files)
                print path2
                foundFiles.append(path2)
    return foundFiles
```

foundFiles[] (after walk thruogh) =

```
[('', 'bg.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj')
('', 'bg.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.vbproj')
('', 'bg.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj')
('', 'bg.FormControls.UnitTests.vbproj')]
('', 'Cooper.Geometry.UnitTests.vbproj')
```

I have this function which works greatly so far. However, the first 4 spaces in each string in foundFiles has the " '', " format which I need to get rid of. Would it be best to use the string.strip, or string.replace, or any other ways of doing it? Thanks in advance!

Edit1:

```
def getUnitTest(path):
foundFiles = []

for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for files in f:
        if files.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj'):
            path2 = os.path.split(files)
            print path2
            foundFiles.append(path2)
foundFiles2= [ str(value for value in file if value) for file in foundFiles]
return foundFiles2
```

This is what I have so far, it still doesn't get rid of the first tuple, am I supposed to change value to what it's actually representing? Sorry if this a dumb question I'm still a newbie programmer.

Comment: Do you mean to say you only need the second element of each tuple in the foundFiles list? You can replace `return foundFiles` with `return [x[1] for x in foundFiles]` in that case

Comment: are you missing some indentation?

Comment: @JordanTrudgett I tried that `return [x[1] for x in foundFiles]` and it still didnt get rid of the first tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replacing whitespace in a tuple**

You're not trying to get rid of part of a string, you're trying to remove empty strings from a tuple (you have a [list](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html) of [tuples](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html) in `foundFiles`), which you can do like this:

*NOTE: As tuples are immutable, we cannot edit them once defined*

```
foundFilesFixed = [str(value for value in file if value) for file in foundFiles]
```

This will copy over all tuple values in `foundFiles` to `foundFilesFixed` as long as they aren't false (empty whitespace, null, etc).

This will replace this:

```
[
    ('', 'bg.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj')
    ('', 'bg.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.vbproj')
    ('', 'bg.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj')
    ('', 'bg.FormControls.UnitTests.vbproj')
]
```

with this:

```
[
    'bg.APDS.UnitTests.vbproj'
    'bg.DatabaseAPI.UnitTests.vbproj'
    'bg.DataManagement.UnitTests.vbproj'
    'bg.FormControls.UnitTests.vbproj'
]
```

I'm making the assumption here that all of your tuples have two values, one empty and one filename. If there's a possibility that these will hold multiple values, you will need to change `str(` in my function to `tuple(`.

**Alternative: Application specific**

As noted by Jordan in the comments, for your example you can just do this:

```
return [str(value[1]) for value in foundFiles]
```

Instead of `return foundFiles`, however, this is unlikely to work for future readers so didn't want to draw focus to it.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to find `*.UnitTests.vbproj` in your `path` directory is to use `glob`:

```
import os, glob

def getUnitTest(path):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.UnitTests.vbproj"))
```

and to print it out one result per line:

```
print "\n".join(getUnitTest(path));
```